# Was Mordechai upset that Ahashverush purposely hid from the rabbis the fact that drinking was like a religion?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Esther 1:8

והשתיה כדת אין אנס כי כן יסד המלך על כל רב ביתו

"The drinking was like a religion. It was no accident that the king kept it a secret from the rabbis of his household."

My understanding of the above - The king made drinking itself a religion, but he didn't want to tell his rabbis about this. Yet, according to Midrash, Mordechai didn't want Jews to attend the king's party and drink there. Could Mordechai have somehow known about this scheme and he was upset that the king didn't tell the royal rabbis about this?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: +1, but I don't see the question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure we are all familiar with the famous gematriya equivalence i.e that barukh Mordechai (בָּרוּךְ מָרְדָּכַי) and arur Haman (אָרוּר הָמָן), is exactly 502.  The question we need to ask is why the number comes out exactly 502.

The answer comes from the story of Ruth.  We know that Ruth in gemetryia is 606 because she started off with 7 Noachide mitzvot, then added 606 when she converted.  In the same manner, since drinking on purim is  כְּנֶגֶד the full 613 mitzvot you'd think  בָּרוּךְ מָרְדָּכַי, etc. should be equal 613.  Instead, the gemetrya is only 502 -- we're missing 111.

111 happens to be the gematryia of אנס, so when the megilla says והשתיה כדת **אין אנס**, it means that it *looked like* the drinking was leshem mitzvah, but in reality we were missing the key component that made it kodesh, and so that is why the chachamim didn't go to the mishteh.

Still, the fact that the Jewish people refrained from having kiddush clubs for a fully 180 days was a serious problem, which is why Mordechai was metaken drinking on Purim ledorot. That is why we have the saying that **"Hashem considers people who get drunk on Purim to be as great as Tzaddikim who stay drunk all year round".**

Comment: Are you sure you don't carry around a gematria calculator App? This is complex but very good. If you can, cite the Hebrew equic. or link a source for the last quote (the bolded one). I'm unfamiliar with it. Happy *hic* Purim.

Comment: Thanks!  That last one is completely made up (as far as I know).  I use it on all my mishloach manot cards.

Comment: I like it :-15)

Comment: Actually the missing 111 is completed from the drinking itself or rather by the regurgitatibg the drink. This is known in Hebrew as קיא which is gematria 111. Hence the over drinking completes the full 613.9